# Parse response retrieved from url in json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to create a parser for login page. I have a url that gives response in json. When not logged in it gives response as :

```
{"status":0,"msg":"Email is Wrong!"}
```

and when loggged in it gives :

```
{"status":1,"msg":"Session is active","session_id":"lp47ngp9hlqtrkunjirqa7ijg5","user_id":"13"}
```

I have no idea how to start this. Please help...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm understanding a real question here, but as I understand it, try using [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to retrieve your json from the url. In the call to ajax, there'll be a parameter called success, that takes a function with one argument. That argument will be the data retrieved from the url. Simply do `obj = eval(data)`, and your data will be parsed and you can access the status as `obj.status`.

Answer (score 1):

Using plain javascript you can use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON string to a Javascript Object.

Something like:

```
var response = JSON.parse([yourJsonString]);
if (response.session_id) {
  // logged in, proceed
} else {
  // not logged in, act accordingly
}
```

JSON.parse is available in modern browsers. For older browsers you need to include a JSON parser like [this one](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (use json2.js)

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Using Bing and JSON</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $.getJSON('url', function (data) {
            alert(data.status); // 1
            alert(data.msg); // List of rooms

        });
    </script>
    <div id="Roomcount">
    </div>
</body>
</html> This is the code on which i am working

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery and jquery.ajax/jquery.get, etc., you will receive a response in the form of a javascript object that you may use to react accordingly.

Jquery is an excellent javascript library very very widely used. It's kind of a defacto standard.

Just google it and you will find a lot of information, tutorials, books. In Stack Overflow you will find a lot of material on this topic.

Comment: There is no mention of using jQuery in the question and it is not hard to parse JSON *without* using jQuery.

Comment: @Matt But there is also no mention on not using it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the jQuery parseJSON method to parse the JSON string into Javascript object
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: if you use jquery.ajax, the conversion is done for you. No need to do this.

Comment: There is no mention of using jQuery in the question and it is not hard to parse JSON *without* using jQuery.

Comment: But you are proposing jquery! (I did not down vote you though)